# Automatically cancel magento 2 pending orders after a specified amount of time?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, cron, order-status, crontab

We found that we sometimes run out of stock/inventory due to orders pending payment. Is there a way to "release" those stock/inventory after a specified amount of time, automatically, without us having to check regularly for orders pending payment and cancelling manually?

Comment: Is my answer working for you ?

Comment: You can check out this extension [auto cancel order](https://www.mageants.com/auto-cancel-order-for-magento-2.html) to automatically cancel the order after a specific time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the solutions is to create a cron job that will cancel the orders left waiting for payment X hour or days after they were created.
That way your stocks would be updated.

Here you can find explanations and examples on how to configure and create cron tasks :
 - https://www.maximehuran.fr/en/create-a-cron-job-with-magento-2/
 - https://www.atwix.com/magento-2/setting-up-cron-jobs/
 - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html

Here it is same logic for Magento 1 : [How to automatically cancel pending orders after a specified amount of time?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/12861/33619)